# clear button in a java application

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My code consists of three classes, say: x(extends JFrame), y(extends JPanel) and z. x has the main function. It has borderLayout and has two panels in it: left and center. Left panel has bunch of JButtons and JTextFields where user inputs his values and those values are used to draw some things into my center panel handled by my y class.

The z class is used by the y class for general calculation purposes. Now I am almost done making the program and am working on a "clear" button in my left panel which will clear all the text user has entered and what has been drawn into my center panel (handled by y class).

What i can do is set some values to their default values and repaint() my center panel but the problem is that there are a LOT of variables and then there are again a lot of variables in my z class(which is instantiated by y).

This is getting confusing and tiresome so i am thinking if there is any way i can (i am going against the rules of garbage collection here) i can kill the instance of y in my x class and make a new one. That will be so neat. Tell me what i should do in such situation. Thanks.

EDIT: i want the clear button to remove what has already been drawn into my panel so can i do this in my x class?

```
remove(myRightpanelInstance);
myRightPanel myRightpanelInstance2 = new myRightPanel();
add(myRightpanelInstance2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

it doesnt work btw.

Comment: I don't understand what you think you're trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to make a clear button for my java application. It clear whatever has been done before and makes the program ready for next calculation.

Comment: share some of your code so that we can get a better idea of what your trying to do please

Comment: What does that have to do with garbage collection? If it makes sense to instantiate a new object, then do it.

Comment: Since I don't know ur implementation. I assume you are creating an object of your Z class inside your Y class's method and calling z class's functions. So, the object is garbage collected when u exit the method. There is no need to clear the values of Z class's variables

Comment: Separate your data (model) from your Swing components (view).  Create one or more separate model classes.

Comment: What is on myRightPanelInstance that you are trying to remove?

Comment: Things drawn from previous input, graphs and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit you want to add a new panel and overwrite the old one. You can simply:

```
 MyRightPanel myRightPanelInstance2 = new myRightPanel();
 add(myRightPanelInstance2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will overwrite the existing panel with the new one.

Make sure this code is in your listener for the clear button. This only happens if you call this code inside the listener.

```
  clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Either above code here or above code in a method and method call here
        }
    })
```

Comment: na it doesn't overwrite the old one for some reason, i did exactly what you said.